# Linking to an old third party DLL in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am porting a C++ project from an old Borland compiler to VisualStudio 2008.  This project uses a third party DLL that I don't have the source code for, so I am unable to recompile or modify it.  The header file for the DLL defines functions along the lines of:

```
extern "C" {
void __stdcall Init(int a, int b);
}
```

However when I try to link to this DLL, VisualStudio says that it cannot find the function _Init@8.  When I look at the DLL I find that the function name is _Init, and not _Init@8 (it seems that the DLL to predates Microsoft adding @8 to stdcall name mangling).

My question is: How can I call funcions in this DLL?  Does VisualStudio simply not support these old DLLs, or is there a flag/setting that I'm missing.  (I am aware that I could use the LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress functions to dynamically call the functions at run-time, but would prefer to not to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice anything that would tell me whether you are doing 32 or 64 bit coding. MSDN has some information on how to create an import library based on a dll that you have no source for. This article is for making a [32 bit import library](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/131313). CHEERS!

Comment: I'm using 32-bit. Although your link didn't directly solve my problem, it did get me thinking along the right lines. The solution was using def file (as described by the link, and as I had already tried using Borland's impdef and implib), but adding aliases in the EXPORT section: '_Init@8 = Init'